# Issue with @Transactional on a public method in a Class used by CXF

Tags: java, spring, cxf, spring-transactions

I'm mixing spring-data and CXF to create a RESTful endpoint that creates neo4j nodes. My structure is a set Interfaces which define the public facing methods, and my implementations which have several private methods under that are called by my public methods.

When I do create a public method, I get a proxy casting issue.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders field com.neuralsandbox.service.PublicCallsPublic.httpHeaders to $Proxy37
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:150)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:37)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:657)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.injectFieldValue(InjectionUtils.java:170)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.injectContextProxiesAndApplication(InjectionUtils.java:921)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.injectContexts(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:365)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.updateClassResourceProviders(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:391)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:151)
... 29 more
```

If I my spring-tx `<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />` I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class $Proxy32]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy32
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:112)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:476)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1598)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:162)
... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy32
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:446)
    at net.sf.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:201)
    ... 48 more
```

I have a GitHub project which has the troubled code:

https://github.com/NicholasAStuart/broken-spring-neo4j-cxf.git

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

Is the `@Transactional` on a concrete class? If so, I'd suggest using the `proxy-target-class="true"` as that's intended for concrete classes.

Note if using CGLIB, the classes must not be final, be visible, and have a default (no argument) constructor.

Comment: It is on a method inside of a concrete class, yes. Once I add that attribute, I get another error. See my addition above.

Comment: @Nicholas Could you put a breakpoint at that error and inspect what underlying class $Proxy32 is... if you find out what class it's trying to proxy, that may help.

Comment: The underlying class is `NodeGraphRepositoryImpl`

Comment: I'm stumped. That class is public and appears to not be final, so I'm not sure why this is happening. The only thing I can think of is that it doesn't have a default constructor, but I'm not certain. It might be worth moving your @Transactional annotations to the interfaces, removing that proxy-target-class, and seeing what happens. Other than that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Looking at this link and the first response, it appears it might just be the lack of a default constructor: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?105261-CGLIB-Proxy-no-default-constructor

Comment: It looks like `NodeGraphRepositoryImpl` does not have a no-arg constructor, which I'm assuming `spring-data-neo4j` is converting my `GraphRepository` into. This is coming into my class through an `@Autowired`.

Comment: Yep, that's the issue. It really seems like you should try out using interfaces for @Transactional. That is Spring's recommendation, in general.

Comment: But this doesn't make sense to me. I can move the `@Transactional` method off to a class that isn't an interface either and as long as it's not a CXF serviceBean, it get's wired okay.

Comment: What doesn't make sense? It can't instantiate a proxy subclass of the NodeGraphRepositoryImpl. If it ends up on a bean that has a no-args constructor, then it works.

Comment: However, my point about using an interface is that it CAN proxy the interface that the NodeGraphRepositoryImpl implements.

Comment: I have 2 classes, both concrete, both with `@Autowired` for interfaces that resolve to `NodeGraphRepositoryImpl`, and both with a method of `@Transactional` publicly exposed. The one I use one of them as a CXF service bean gets an error, the one I autowire to another class works fine.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. You might debug to the Enhancer lines that create and see how things differ there for each bean. Not really familiar with the CGLIB code but maybe you'll see a diff and be able to make something of it.